# The inside of the loop is asynchronous, how to synchronize the outside

Tags: flutter

for example:

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> list = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
  gogo(list);
  print('main end');
}

void gogo(List list) async {
  list.forEach((element) async {
    await pS(element);
  });

  print('gogo end');
}

Future pS(String s) async {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    print(s);
  });
}
```

will output:

gogo end
main end
1
2
3
4

The result I am looking forward to:

1
2
3
4
gogo end
main end

Comment: use `for (var element in list) {...`, not `list.forEach((element) ...`

Comment: I changed to `void gogo(List list) async {
  // list.forEach((element) async {
  //   await pS(element);
  // });

  for(String element in list){
    await pS(element);
  }

  print('gogo end');
}` but not ok

Comment: you need `await gogo(list);` and `await Future.delayed` too

Comment: got it , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you expect, I also explained in the example.

```dart
// Create an async main method to work with Future
void main() async {
  List<String> list = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
  await gogo(list);
  print('main end');
}

Future gogo(List list) async {
  // Use this method if you want to run all functions at the same time
  // and wait until all functions are completed
  //
  // You can't use List.foreach() because it is not a Future function
  // so you have no way to await it
  await Future.wait([
    for (var element in list) pS(element),
  ]);

  print('gogo end');
}

Future pS(String s) async {
  // You also need to await this function
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    print(s);
  });
}
```

Comment: ty, and I changed `await Future.wait([
    for (var element in list) pS(element),
  ]);` to  `for (var element in list) await pS(element);` then get the same result

Comment: You can do it but all `pS` functions will run one by one, not at the same time. Ex: Instead of run "wait 1 second -> print 1 2 3 4 at the same time" it will run like "wait 1 second -> print 1 -> wait 1 second -> print 2 -> wait 1 second -> print 3 ...."